# Why does the event.type function return a name error?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a simple maze game using PyGame as a beginners project, but when i try to use `event.type` it says,

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple_maze.py", line 22, in <module>
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
NameError: name 'event' is not defined
```

For reference, this is my current code.

```
import pygame
screendim = (500, 500)
blu = (0, 0, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
sc = (0, 0)
pr = 50
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screendim)
pygame.draw.circle(screen, blu, (250, 10), 10)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, pygame.Rect(0, 25, 450, 15)) 
pygame.display.flip()
play = True
while play:
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
```

Any ideas?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: `event` doesn't exist if you don't create it - and it seems you didn't create it. Probably you didn't use `for event in pygame.even.get()`, or you use `event.type` outside this `for`-loop. But we can't give better answer if you dpn't show full error message (Traceback) which shows more and you didn't show code which makes problem.

Comment: full error may only suggest that you have wrong indentations and this line is not inside loop `for event in pygame.event.get():`

Comment: Which code specifically is the for loop supposed to be around? Sorry, I'm pretty new to both pygame and this website so I don't really know what to do

Comment: Maybe find tutorial which shows how to do it. ie. [Program Arcade Games With Python And Pygame](http://programarcadegames.com/). There will also need something more inside this `if`

Answer (score 1):

`event` is not object which exist all time - you have to create it

```
for event in pygame.event.get(): 
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        print(event) # do something with this information about key event
```

You should see this in every tutorial - ie. [Program Arcade Games With Python And Pygame](http://programarcadegames.com/).

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I missed that in the tutorials, but you were very helpful. Thank you!